# Show total number of local changes per file in git status

Tags: git

I would like to see the number of **local** changes I have made, in a list similar to `git status`. Something like this:

- MyExample.cpp (3)
- AnotherFile.cpp (17)

Where if I run `git difftool MyExample.cpp` it will show 3 local changes.

I want this so I can manually-inspect the files with the fewest local changes first, to reduce my `git status` list size quicker and defer the files with the largest number of changes until the end.

I tried `git diff --stat` but it seems to show the total number of remote/local changes

Comment: Are you talking about changes in your worktree? What do you mean by *local* changes?

Comment: @FelixKling I only want to count the number of local changes I have made to each file. For example, I may have modified 3 lines in MyExample.cpp

Comment: So you want `git status` but sorted by the number of changes?

Comment: @FelixKling it doesn't need to be sorted, I just want to be able to see the number of changes. If it can be sorted, great.

Comment: `git diff --stat` should actually do exactly what you want: *"Show changes between the working tree and the index or a tree [...]"* . This is assuming that you checked out a branch and edited some files. If that's not your case then you are have provide more information about the status of your git repo.

Comment: @FelixKling git diff --stat is counting more than my local changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git status` simply does not do that.  It runs the internal equivalent of `git diff --name-status --cached` (to compare `HEAD` vs index to report on `changes staged for commit`), and runs the internal equivalent of `git diff --name-status` (to compare index vs work-tree to report on `changes not staged for commit`).  The `--name-status` flag causes the internal diff to *quit and move on to the next file* as soon as it knows that the files *are or are not different*, without actually figuring out what the differences are.  Hence, `git status` simply *cannot* tell you *how* different two files are.

To get what you want, you'll need to run `git diff` yourself, rather than having `git status` run `git diff --name-status` for you.  That way you can set your own flags.

> I tried `git diff --stat` but it seems to show the total number of remote/local changes ...

There's no such thing as "remote/local changes".

Git stores *files*.  Every commit has a full and complete snapshot of every file.  You can compare two commits, which tells Git to compare the files within the snapshots.  Having extracted, say, `dir/file1` from snapshot A and `dir/file1` from snapshot B, `git diff` can now *calculate* the differences between those two files, and report a set of instructions by which `a/dir/file1` can be changed into `b/dir/file1`.

Counting up those instructions gets you the `--stat` version of that diff.

The `git diff` command is not restricted to looking *only* at two commits: it can also compare one commit to your index, or one commit to your work-tree, or your index to your work-tree.  Since `git status` works by running *two* `git diff`s, you can get what *you* want by running *two* `git diff`s.  Tell the first one to compare the `HEAD` commit to the index, the way `git status` tells the first one to compare `HEAD` vs index.  Tell your second `git diff` to compare index vs work-tree, the way `git status` tells the second diff to compare index vs work-tree.

Comment: I ran git diff --stat for file X. It says '2', however, when I run git difftool on X P4V says there is only one change.

Comment: I think git diff --stat is showing two sets of totals and adding them. I can see a green plus sign and a red negative sign next to file ''X' mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: Yes, `git diff --stat` is counting up the change instructions, which are `+` (add a line) or `-` (delete a line). Your diff tool, whatever it is, produces *its own* diffs, which may be a different set of instructions. The only promises Git makes are that if you follow the instructions, applying those changes to the A version of the file, they produce the B version. Your difftool may make the same promise (it's pretty common these days, diffs that don't actually result in changing A to B are not good) but it doesn't promise to produce the *same* diffs, nor to count them the same way.

Comment: Okay I think I know what git diff --stat is doing, it is counting the number of changed lines in the previous, counting the number of changed lines in the current and summing them. In contrast, P4V is grouping the changes together, combining sequential lines in to one "change".